# C# pointer to struct array

Tags: c#, pascal

Hi I would like to create a pointer to struct array
I have a 2 structs like this

```
public struct TRecord
{
    string Key;
    string Value;
}

public struct TDB
{
    public int Count;
    TRecord[] Records;
}
```

but because I am writing a plugin for Delphi app which passes DBPointer pointer (DBPointer has an array of data) I need to point DBPointer to TDB so I can get the data out of it. When trying to do this like

```
public unsafe TDB* DBPointer; //DBPointer points to TDB struct which has struct array
```

I get

```
Error   CS0208  Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type
```

and as I read I can't declare a pointer to a string and a struct
So I don't know what to do now because if writing this in pascal it works fine

```
type TRecord = record
    Key: shortstring;
    Value:  shortstring;
end;

type TPRecord = record
    Key: PChar;
    Value:  PChar;
end;

type TDB = record
    Count: integer;
    Records: array [0..255] of TRecord;
end;
PTDB = ^TDB;

function ReadValue(Key: PChar; DBPointer: PTDB): PChar; stdcall;
var a,i: integer;
    SKey: shortstring;
begin
Result:='';
SKey:=shortstring(Key);
a:=DBPointer^.Count;
if (a>length(DBPointer^.Records)) then a:=length(DBPointer^.Records);    //ochrana
for i:=1 to a do
begin
if (DBPointer^.Records[i-1].Key=SKey) then
    begin Result:=StrPCopy(Param1,DBPointer^.Records[i-1].Value); exit; end;
    end;
end;
```

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: Why are you using unsafe types at all? There's a reason you have to give them an extra keyword - they're considered unsafe...

Comment: @fredrik "I need to point DBPointer to TDB so I can get the data out of it" - interop with unmanaged code is one of many legitimate uses of `unsafe` code; there are uses even in purely managed code too, of course (although `Span<T>` fixes many of those)

Comment: so anyone has any idea what to do?

Comment: @Persona: obviously not yet. Please be patient. Perhaps someone comes along who knows an answer, perhaps not. FWIW, what about writing the plugin in Delphi? Is that not an option?

Comment: not that confident in Pascal (Delphi) so would rather do it in C# if possible